# Test SQL Db Connection

Tags: .net, sql

Is there any way to test whether particular database server is connected or not? Like ping operation.

I know some alternate way -test SQL Connection opening. Reason to not use that approach is my app is continuosly at each t seconds test the connection.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Not sure why I'm doing this, considering you rarely accept answers, but here goes. Your question brings up a lot of issues, many of the implied.  So bear with me....

**Connectivity & Me**

Connectivity can mean a lot of things.  At a much lower layer, as  @Paddy points out, PING will tell you if the OS is connected to a network you can reach.  But a computer can be connected and SQL could be stopped, offline, or otherwise malfunctioning.  SQL could be online, but a firewall blocks access from the requesting computer.  The requesting computer could lack permissions.  The list goes on.

My point here is that:

> *The ability to open a connection to SQL Server is* **the method** *to test connectivity.*

If it were me I would put put a small ADO test on an async-thread.  The test would try to open a connection using a short timeout.

**Solving symptom or the problem?**

SQL Server really is designed, and generally conceived of, as a high availability product.  Meaning, if your SQL access is going out so much that you want to test for it (beyond a general error handler) I would suggest you solve the avilability issue.  Even the most basic install combined with lots of bad luck should allow for 95% or higher up time.

**Using SQL SMO to test**

If I haven't dissuaded you by this point, there is an alternative.  SQL SMO (the replacement for SQL DMO) is a series of objects that allow programmatic access to SQL server management.

The code below will require references to a few objects:

- Microsoft.SqlServer.ConnectionInfo.dll
- Microsoft.SqlServer.Smo.dll
- Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Sdk.Sfc.dll
- Microsoft.SqlServer.SqlEnum.dll
- Microsoft.SqlServer.SQLWmiManagmenet.dll
- Microsoft.SqlServer.WmiEnum.dll

You can use this [getting started](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms162129.aspx) article to see how to setup a project.  Note you will need WINDOWS permissions (as opposed to SQL authentication) to connect to the SQL Server in question.

Now onto the code :

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Smo;
using Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Common;
using Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Smo.Wmi;

namespace SQL_SMO_Test {
 class Program {

    public const string SQL_SERVICE_BASENAME = "MSSQL";

    public static bool SQLServiceIsRunning (string SQLServerName ) {
      string[]           nameComponents;
      string             ComputerName;     
      string             InstanceName;     
      string             ServiceName;          
      ManagedComputer    mc;
      ServiceCollection  serviceList;

      //split up SQL Name
      nameComponents = SQLServerName.Split('\\');
      ComputerName   = nameComponents[0];
      InstanceName   = nameComponents.Length > 1 ? nameComponents[1] : "";
      ServiceName    = SQL_SERVICE_BASENAME + 
                           ((InstanceName.Length>0) ? "$" + InstanceName : "");

       //get WMI Computer object
       mc          = new ManagedComputer(ComputerName);
       serviceList = mc.Services;


       //find any SQL Services & See if it's our instance
       foreach (Service s in serviceList) {
          if (s.Type.Equals(ManagedServiceType.SqlServer) ) {
             Console.WriteLine("Service Found --" + s.Name);
             if ( (!ServiceName.Contains('$')) || s.Name == ServiceName ) {
                Console.WriteLine("..Correct Instance found" + s.Name);
                if (s.ServiceState.Equals(ServiceState.Running) ){
                    Console.WriteLine("....Service is Running");
                    return true;
                }
             }
          }
       } //end foreach()

       Console.WriteLine("service not found, or stopped");
       return false; //service not found, or stopped

    } //end SQLServiceIsRunning

                        /* format: servername\instanceIfAny */ 
    public static bool SQLIsRunning( string SQLServerName ) {
      Server  srv;

      Console.WriteLine("SERVICE RUNNING (" + SQLServerName + ") ?" );
      Console.WriteLine("------------------------------" );

      if (! SQLServiceIsRunning(SQLServerName) ) {
         return false;
      }
      Console.WriteLine("------------------------------" );

      srv = new Server(SQLServerName);
      try {
          Console.WriteLine("Status: " + srv.Status.ToString() );
          return true;
      } catch (Exception ex) {
          Console.WriteLine("Exception: " + ex.ToString() );
      }

       return false;

    } //end SQLIsRunning()


    static void Main(string[] args) {
      bool result = SQLIsRunning("MST-SQL01.mst.com");

      Console.WriteLine("-----------");
      Console.WriteLine("Press any key to close...");
      Console.ReadKey();


    } //end main()
  }
}
```

Comment: It seems useful, but isn't it heavy operation? Sorry,i have no more idea about SMO. So can't say more.

Comment: "Isn't it heavy" -- depends on your perspective.  It's and out of process, and likely network call, like all database connection.  So you'll measure time in milliseconds, not nanoseconds.  But it is way faster than waiting on a connection timeout. However, I stand by my assertion -- a connection is THE METHOD to test DB availability.   Put your connection test on an async thread so you don't care about wait times.

Answer (score 0):

You can ping a server:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.networkinformation.ping.aspx

But this will not tell you if the DB is up.  Opening a connection (which authenticates etc. is  probably your only way).  Why are you continually pollling this way?

Comment: I want to prevent action being performed in application if database is not available that's why. So if db is not connected app will be locked.

Comment: Why not just provide some error handling for the case when the database is down (this should be infrequent, I hope), as opposed to using up resource continually pinging this server to check?